# Symfony 4 forms - simple serverside validation and php type declarations

Tags: php, symfony

My forms are standard, except the submit button

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'action.save'|trans }}" formnovalidate />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I disabled html5 validation with "formnovalidate" in the submit button,
because, for example here (Entity User)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="assert.notblanc")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 2,  minMessage = "assert.minmessage",
 *      max = 50, maxMessage = "assert.maxmessage"
 * )
 */
private $fullName;
```

there was only a simple message "Please match the requested format" (Firefox),
regarding length. Not so nice.

But now, with "serverside validation", I can't use PHP Type Declaration as usual.

```
public function getFullName(): string
{
    return $this->fullName;
}

public function setFullName(string $fullName): void
{
    $this->fullName = $fullName;
}
```

If an empty FullName is submitted, I get an symfony error

> Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "fullName".

or this when adding a new user

> Return value of App\Entity\User::getFullName() must be of the type string, null returned

This

```
public function getFullName(): ?string
{
    return $this->fullName;
}

public function setFullName(?string $fullName): void
{
    $this->fullName = $fullName;
}
```

solves the problem, but is this the usual way, the make everything "nullable"? 
I wonder also ... Asserts will check the Entity values, after values are setted?

**----- UPDATE (here are the user controller functions) ------**

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     path = "/user-add",
 *     name = "user_add"
 * )
 */
public function addUser(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    // Update and check user
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        // Save it
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Your changes were saved!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
    }

    return $this->render('user/user_add_update.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route(
 *     path = "/user-update/{id<[1-9]\d*>}",
 *     name = "user_update"
 * )
 */
public function updateUser(int $id, Request $request)
{
    // Get user
    $user = $this->userRepository->find($id);
    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user found for id ' . $id);
    }

    // Update and check user
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        // Save it
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Your changes were saved!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
    }

    return $this->render('user/user_add_update.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you handling this request?

You must use this construction

```
public function someControllerMethod(Request $reqest) {
  $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);
  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form->isSubmited && $form->isValid()){
      $user = $form->getData();
      // do some stuff
      return $this->redirect ...
  } else {
      return $this->render('editingPage.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
      ]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: hello, I think my functions are similar ;)

Comment: @ABSimon instead of $user = new User(); use my construction and after form validation you can get new entity $user = $form->getData();

Comment: Thanks, know I see ;) "getFullName(): ?string" is still needed, but I can skip "setFullName(?string $fullName)". Simular to https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/src/Entity/User.php.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says `getFullName` has to return a string. Your getter method is:

```
public function getFullName(): string
{
    return $this->fullName;
}
```

Before you have declared:

```
private $fullName;
```

If you change it to:

```
private $fullName = '';
```

that is, assign a default value, the getter will return an empty string and the error shouldn't be thrown.

Comment: thank you. yes this is also an alternative to "getFullName(): ?string"

Comment: @ABSimon I think it's little bit cleaner, since you don't want to allow your setter method to accept `null` and your getter method should strictly return `string`. I use mainly Django and there the problem is solved better, allowing the user to specify `blank` and `null` to boolean value. With Doctrine you can make a field nullable or not, but there is no option to make field *blankable* i.e. don't allow null, but allow empty string.